# How to find patches with data in Raster and then how to extract those patches?

Tags: raster, gdal, gdalwarp, rasterio

I have a single band raster file as drawn in the labeled image attached.
[image]

The size of raster is around 4k pixel in each x and y axis. Large part of this raster is empty. Only in small portions of the raster contains data as labeled. Is there any efficient way I can extract rectangular patches around the data portions of the large `tif` raster file?

Any pythonic way using `gdal` or `rasterio` or some other package.

**What I have done so far:**
I have followed from `sklearn.feature_extraction.image`way to extract 2D patches where there is data as follows.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches_2d
im = imageio.imread(largeFilePath) # reading the large image
x, y = np.nonzero(im) # taking xy locations with non zero values

# determining xleft, xright, yleft and yright of the non zero area in 
raster 
xl,xr = x.min(),x.max() 
yl,yr = y.min(),y.max() 

#Extraing the non zero area from my original raster
only_desired_area = im[xl:xr+1, yl:yr+1]

# my desired window to extract 
window_shape = (480, 480)

# 2D Ptaches extraction
B = extract_patches_2d(only_desired_area, window_shape, max_patches=100)
```

**Issue:**
This doesn't have georeference information because I haven't used `gdal` or `rasterio`

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38912569/1446289

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. But do you think that I will lose all the meta data information if I use ndimage instead of gdal or rasterio?

Comment: Are you primarily interested in georeferencing the extracted data? If so, you can use an affine transformation in Rasterio based on the numpy pixel locations: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/georeferencing.html

Comment: Excuse me for me naive questions but I want to extract patches/data first and then would like to know about the extracted patches georeferencing. Or If I can do both in the same function/code/command.

Comment: Here is another algorithm that could be useful: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-label-py

Comment: Do you need something else than gdal_translate https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html with either -srcwin or -projwin option? Pythonic way is to use https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Translate? Or is the problem to find automatically the areas where you have data?

Comment: The problem is automatically find the area where there is data and extract it from the original image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668750/detecting-rectangles-sub-arrays-of-same-element-value-in-2-d-list

Comment: You have two questions 1) how to find the patches and 2) how to extract them - these are very different problems (1 is hard, 2 is easy) - please [edit] your question to clarify which you want here. In either case we need to see what you have managed so far in terms of code.

Comment: I have edited my question.